# Error: variable "Point a" has initializer but incomplete type. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, oop

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point;

int main()
{
    Point a(5, 6);
    
    a.getAll();
    
    return 0;
}

class Point
{
private:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
public:
    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    
    Point(){}
    
    //setters
    void setX(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
    
    void setY(int y)
    {
        this->y = y;
    }
    
    
    //getters
    int getX()
    {
        return this->x;
    }
    
    int getY()
    {
        return this->y;
    }
    
    void getAll()
    {
        std::cout << "x = " << this->x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y = " << this->y << std::endl;
    }
    
    
    ~Point(){}
};
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:
*[Error] variable 'Point a' has initializer but incomplete type.*

What should I change or include to prevent that error?

........................................................................

Comment: The class has been forward declared, so it doesn't know how to allocate space for it, let alone whether it has a constructor taking 2 params and a function `getAll`.

Comment: You may want move your Point class to a header and include that at the top of your source file that has `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

`class Point;` is a so-called forward declaration. In layman terms, it only declares that there is a class type called `Point` nothing more. However, to create an object of that type more is needed. Move the definition of `Point` before its usage.

Change

```
class Point;
int main() {
    Point a(5,6);
}
struct Point {
    Point(int a,int b){}
};
```

to

```
struct Point {
    Point(int a,int b){}
};
int main() {
    Point a(5,6);
}
```

Comment: Nicely written, and I'm glad you've got rid of all the junk in the class. Fun fact of course is that `Point` can live entirely within `main`. It's how we did lambda functions before C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the function to use the class `Point` after the declaration of the class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
private:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
public:
    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    
    Point(){}
    
    //setters
    void setX(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
    
    void setY(int y)
    {
        this->y = y;
    }
    
    
    //getters
    int getX()
    {
        return this->x;
    }
    
    int getY()
    {
        return this->y;
    }
    
    void getAll()
    {
        std::cout << "x = " << this->x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y = " << this->y << std::endl;
    }
    
    
    ~Point(){}
};

int main()
{
    Point a(5, 6);
    
    a.getAll();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `Point` needs to be "seen" by the compiler before the any instantiation of `Point`. (In other words, move `main` towards the end of the source file.) If only a forward declaration has been given, then the type is said to be *incomplete*.

In this respect C++ compiles the code "downwards", rather like you would read a book. (It's not always true but it does apply here).

Also note that you should only write "setters" if you need them. All they achieve is the circumvention of encapsulation. Drop the explicit destructor too. Use base member initialisation in the constructor rather than setting the variables in the constructor body:

```
Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) // this is unambiguous
{     
}
```

If you need your type to be polymorphic then write

```
virtual ~Point() = default;
```

Finally, rather than `getAll`, overload `std::ostream <<` for your type. Then you could write

```
std::cout << a;
```